# How to deal with GeoPDFs in Android/iOS

Tags: pdf, gis, geotiff

I have to build a mobile app to edit a geospatial pdf but I don't know how to tackle it. I found that **I have to convert the pdf to GeoTiff first.**

Does anybody know how to deal with GeoPdfs in Android/iOS?

**Note**: I need to load and edit the pdf as Avenza Maps does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stackoverflow! Is it safe to assume you are just looking for help on how to convert the GeoPDF to a GeoTiff? Or are you looking for help in general for how to go about building an Android application that allows users to edit the GeoPDF?

Comment: @BrandonHaugen I have change the question, thanks for your observation.

Comment: @SilvioPalacios, did you find that you need to convert the PDF to TIFF first to make it easy to display on screen? Or was there some other reason that this is necessary? Android/iOS both have capabilities for rendering PDFs on screen, these won't have any idea what to do with the geo data though. This is where you will need to make decisions about how to move forward and either find (open source or commercial) solution or build something that will do exactly what you need. Either way, Stackoverflow may not be right place to get help with this type of question ("how do I build XYZ").

Comment: @SilvioPalacios, were you able to get it done loading geoPDF into the map? Currently, I am using Osmdroid, but it does not have geoPdf support? Any direction on this problem would help